# How do you open and close a new database connection with ActiveRecord Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have some workloads that need to increase `WORK_MEM` and `TEMP_BUFFERS`.  The problem is, once I do this, the connection (session) is not closed and is returned to the pool.  This means the extra memory usage isn't temporary because I can't change `TEMP_BUFFERS` back without destroying the session.

I imagine the workflow going something like this:

```
conn = ActiveRecord.create_new_connection
conn.execute <<-SQL
  SET TEMP_BUFFERS TO '512MB';
  -- do some memory intensive 
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE .....;
  UPDATE ....;
SQL
conn.close
```

Or maybe there is a way to close the current connection and have the pool crate a new one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like [`new_connection` is a private method](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool/new_connection), which is what we need to manually create a connection outside being part of the pool,

Then, upon inspecting the source code, you can do something like this:

```
connection_specification = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.spec
# i.e.
#   connection_specification.adapter_method == 'postgresql_connection'
#   connection_specification.config == {:adapter=>"postgresql", :encoding=>"unicode", :pool=>5, :database=>"someapp_development"}

connection = ActiveRecord::Base.send(
  connection_specification.adapter_method, 
  connection_specification.config
)

# DEBUG:
puts connection.active?
# => true

connection.execute <<-SQL
  SET TEMP_BUFFERS TO '512MB';
  -- do some memory intensive 
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE .....;
  UPDATE ....;
SQL

connection.disconnect!

# DEBUG:
puts connection.active?
# => false
```

Comment: This solution does work.  However, it pointed me in the right direction of a simpler solution, `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset!`.

Comment: Take note though that `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` returns a connection from the pool, which is ok if this is fine with your spec requirements :)